# Google Sheets Send Custom Ranges to Emails Automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to send emails with a specific PDF attachment to various emails from google sheets using script editor.

I know there are threads that I can visit on this site that can help me, but I am not too well versed in Google Sheets Script Editor.  I studied VBA and SQL, but only up to mildly advanced and even this was about 5 years ago.  This is my current situation:

I am trying to setup a system where my customers are sent an automated email from Google which shows them their specific information and a short message.  I think I understand the message aspect of this, but **I have no idea how to select the information.**  The link below will take you to the type of content I am trying to send:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=16VGcID3a5cT9SXFP4IrrwFbamq_01Na0t6jONCrHm0E

In the link, I included an example of what I am working with.  I tried my best to replicate the actual file as much as possible (without including confidential information), but the sheet layout and name are all the same as my file.  I understand if additional information is needed - in which I will try my best to comply.

Lastly, I wanted to send the table as a PDF attachment and include a short Subject and Body.

Unfortunately, I don't have a starting point.

I have tried a few things, but I'm really shooting in the dark.  I looked online at tutorials and followed them, but they didn't include everything that I needed, and those that did were WAY to complicated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out the [guides on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for SO, and have a look at the [Google Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) in relation to your question. Everything you need is fairly straightforward, and well explained in Google's documentation.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the hard love.  I worked with a few tutorials and began working on a script and even though it's not done yet - I went through a few rough drafts and am getting closer to getting what I want.  Once I get a point where I am happy with what I made, I will upload for some input.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

```html
function emailWashburn() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(".02 Dup").activate();

  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C6");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
  
  var nameRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C3");
  var currentName = nameRange.getValues();
  
  var dateRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C7");
  var currentDate = dateRange.getValues();
  
  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("DUP_Body").getValue();
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(6);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName('temp');
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('.02 Dup'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:E12').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('temp'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'.02 Dup\'!A1:E12').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'.02 Dup\'!A1:E12').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'.02 Dup\'!A1:E12').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("temp").getRange(1, 1, 12, 12);
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yk6l1etGAwWE7hQ48u17GoxezRjIEv07WLZ_O3Chmrc/edit#gid=0").getSheetByName("Temp");
  
  ss.copyTo(destination);
  
  var emailAttachment = DriveApp.getFileById(destination.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");
  emailAttachment.setName("Washburn" + ".pdf");
  
  var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}", currentName).replace("{date}", currentDate);
  var subjectLine = "Attn: Updated fuel prices effective as of " + currentDate;
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subjectLine, messageBody, {
  htmlBody: messageBody,
  attachments: [emailAttachment]
  });
 
  var spreadsheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheets.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('temp'), true);
  spreadsheets.deleteActiveSheet();
}
```

My main issue is on line 29 and this is because the formula is meant to copy and paste an entire sheet to a new sheet to a spreadsheet - but I tried to counter this by specifying both copying range and the pasting range.

Also, I know for fact that this is not the easiest way of going about this (sending a defined range to an email recipient as a PDF), but after digging through a few tutorials - this seemed to be a good way of doing so.

If this is not a good way, and I am just spinning my wheels - please let me know so I can try a different angle.